# queue classic returns PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "pid" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, queue-classic

When I do

```
bundle exec rake qc:work
```

to run queue_calssic, I get this error

```
rake aborted!
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "pid" does not exist
LINE 1: ..., locked_by = NULL WHERE locked_by NOT IN (SELECT pid FROM p...
                                                             ^
/home/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/queue_classic-3.0.3/lib/queue_classic/conn_adapter.rb:18:in `exec'
/home/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/queue_classic-3.0.3/lib/queue_classic/conn_adapter.rb:18:in `block in execute'
/home/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/queue_classic-3.0.3/lib/queue_classic/conn_adapter.rb:14:in `synchronize'
/home/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/queue_classic-3.0.3/lib/queue_classic/conn_adapter.rb:14:in `execute'
/home/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/queue_classic-3.0.3/lib/queue_classic.rb:104:in `unlock_jobs_of_dead_workers'
/home/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/queue_classic-3.0.3/lib/queue_classic/worker.rb:42:in `start'
/home/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/queue_classic-3.0.3/lib/queue_classic/tasks.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/andreas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => qc:work
```

When I do `psql --version` i get `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5`

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

Comment: Do you have the entire query? The most important part is missing, the function or view where "pid" doesn't exist. Wild guess: You're not using version 9.3 but an older one, where procpid is used. pg_stat_activity changed this columnname in version 9.2

Comment: The query is done in the queue_classic gem. I don't think the error is there. I think you are on to something when you point at my environment. But, when I  do `psql --version` i get `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5`

Comment: --version show the version of psql, not of the PostgreSQL-server. What does this query tell you: SELECT version();

Comment: # SELECT version();
                                                   version                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.1.13 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1, 64-bit
(1 row)
Right on the buck! Can you make an answer and tell me how to upgrade the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the entire query? The most important part is missing, the function or view where "pid" doesn't exist. Wild guess: You're not using version 9.3 but an older one, where procpid is used. pg_stat_activity changed this columnname in version 9.2

Use this query to get the server version:

```
SELECT version();
```

An upgrade to a newer version can be done by a [dump-restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/upgrading.html) or [pg_upgrade](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgupgrade.html).